# How to get the good version of SDL_mixer?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-mixer

Here is the corrected version of your question:

I watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WficzyoTSsg&t) to learn how to code a video game in C. I followed all the steps at the beginning of the video and downloaded all the files he mentioned. At 2:39, he opened the SDL-mixer file, and in the video, the guy had a directory full of different files.

[image: Screen from the video]

However, when I downloaded the file on my PC, I got this directory:

[image: My directory]

I can only add the SDL2_mixer.dll file, but there is no .h file. I tried to download the same version as in the video, but I encountered the same issue (downloaded from here: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_mixer/releases because on the SDL website, I got a page not found).

I hope someone knows how to help me get the correct version of SDL_mixer.

Comment: There are multiple `.zip`s at your link. It seems they downloaded the `SDL2_mixed-devel-2.8.0-VC` one (for Visual Studio). There's also `SDL2_mixed-devel-2.8.0-mingw` for MinGW. While you've downloaded `SDL2_mixer-2.8.0.zip`.

Comment: For sure, with the correct file, it works better. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some real code you hav written. Also the screenshot is not helpful at all. What is the expected result?

Comment: Its fine, i just download the wrong file.